# Part of speech of "that"

Tags: phrases, parts-of-speech, clauses, subordinators

In the phrase:

> *He demonstrated that he was true*

1. What word class does *that* belong to?
2. In general, which word classes can it belong to? For example, relative pronoun, determiner, ...

THX

Answer (score 0):

It is a *complementiser*, or *subordinator*. You could call it a kind of conjunction if you like.

"That" can also be a demonstrative pronoun or determiner. It sometimes also appears to be a relative pronoun (similar to "which"), but there is a preferable analysis where it is a complementiser and there is a suppressed "which".

**Edit**: correct "adjective" to "determiner".

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me an example with "that" functioning as an adjective?

Comment: No, I can't, because it isn't (though I think it used to be analysed that way). I mean "determiner", and have edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @LISA When I learned grammar (around the time Grendl was a pup), sentences were analyzed in terms of parts of speech -- verbs, nouns, adjectives, etc.  The modern way is to distinguish between parts of speech and the roles words play in sentences.  For instance, adjectives describe nouns and they may be compared (*red*, *redder*, *reddest*); determiners select nouns but don't describe them (*that* car over there, but no *thatter* car).  Both parts of speech, adjectives and determiners, take the role of noun modifier in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence below, the word *that* is a subordinator:

> He demonstrated that he was true.

... in some grammars this is called  a "subordinating conjunction" or a "complementizer".

The word *that* can also be a determinative:

- That journey was quick.

In some grammars if the determinative *that* isn't followed by a noun, it is regarded as a pronoun:

- That was quick.

It can also be an adverb:

- I didn't realise it was that big.

**Relative that**

> That is the dog that we saw yesterday.

*That* may be considered a relative pronoun by some grammars. However, a number of very important modern grammars, for example the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* regard the *that* which we see before relative clauses as the same *that* which we see in the Original Poster's example. In other words, they regard it as a subordinator in both cases.