# What is the function of "that" in sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I have heard the following type of sentence in many stories, podcasts, etc.:

> All were happy **that** the bus suddenly came and everyone got upset.

I would rather wonder whether conjunction *that* is an adverb clause introducer here, or is another type of clauses.

Comment: Answered at [Part of speech of that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290808/part-of-speech-of-that/290812#290812), which was closed for lack of research. // The sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: "That" is a subordinator. It is introducing the subordinate content clause "that the bus suddenly came and everyone got upset" which is functioning as complement to the adjective "happy".

Comment: Btw, I agree with Edwin that the sentence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @BillJ: It may introduce that clause, or it may only introduce the first clause and not the conjoined clauses. That would be something like _All were happy when the bus came, and (then) everyone got upset_, to clarify it. That doesn't make much more sense, but at least things happened in temporal sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commonly used term for the "that" in "They were happy that the bus came" is *complementizer*.  It is added at the beginning of the sentence "the bus came" in order to convert it into the *complement* "that the bus came".

This, in turn, is the object complement of the preposition "at", which here is understood.  The complement can be pronominalized to "it"/"this"/"that", in which case the "at" is explicit: "The bus came, and they were happy at that."

"that" complements also occur as the subject and object complements of verbs: "That the bus came pleased them," "They knew that the bus came."  Some nouns, like "fact", can also take a "that" complement: "The fact that the bus came surprised them."

Comment: The content clause introduced by the subordinator "that" is a direct complement of the adjective "happy", the item that licenses it. There is no 'understood' preposition "at"

Comment: Because I am not a native speaker, I could not realize that it does not make much sense ,so I apologize for it. Isn't it better to say "All were happy but the bus suddenly came and everyone got upset." or do you suggest a better sentence instead?